# how to return the number of days according on its month using java

Tags: java

I was given this assignment for my homework:

> create a program in java that accepts an unsigned integer n and return the number of days according to its month. For example if n = 6, the return value is 30 because 6th month of june has 30 days. Assume no leap year.

This is my attempt, but it doesn't work as expected.  Can anyone give me pointers as to why.

```
public class daysmonths {
   public static void main(String []args) {
     for (int i = 1; i<=12; i++){
       int e = f(i);
       System.out.println(i + " = " + e + " days ");
   }
}   
    public static int f(int i){
       if ((i == 1)|(i == 3)|(i == 5)|(i == 7)|(i == 8)|(i == 10)|(i == 12))
         return 31;
       else if ((i == 4)|(i == 6)|(i == 9)|(i == 11))
         return 30;
       else
         return 28;             
}

}
```

Comment: Your homework for today?

Comment: typical homework statements :p

Comment: yes its my homework do yo know how to answer it?

Comment: yes , me and many other people should know how to code this problem. but i guess homework is suppose to do by yourself :)

Comment: @MarkDan11 No one here will spoon feed you, try it first and when you can't get there post it with what you have done, then lot of people will help you to get there

Comment: ok this just my 1st time to ask ill try it

Comment: i have my codes here ill post it

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I've edited your question to give you an idea how to approach this kind of question on this site.  You could improve it further by editing in what actual error message you see.  In addition - double check the code you pasted - I suspect you have a typo (extra `}` character).  The edit doesn't necessarily make it a perfect question - it's probably still a duplicate (see comment above), but hopefully it gives you some help on how to ask in future.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code uses the java Calendar class by setting it's month to the input month and getting its max date by getActualMaximum() method. Also it will return 29 for leap years.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        int month = 6;
        Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
        System.out.println(cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
    }
```

Comment: Great, that makes the answer more useful, I think :)

Comment: thx sir Amol does it also accepts the unsigned integr n? and how bout if other months because only month of june is on the code.

Comment: You can get the number from user input using the Scanner class. For unsigned intergers, u can add validation using if condition so that the input is in between 1 to 12.